# How to redirect Node.js app to HTTPS using nginx?

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx

I have a Node app on port 3000 and I am trying to figure out how to redirect it to https so that it can be accessed at https://localhost:3000/ instead of http://localhost:3000. The setup I currently have redirects http to https, but gives me a '502 Bad Gateway Error' and does not show my app. Any ideas what could be wrong with my setup?

nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/server-crt.pem; 
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/server-key.pem;

  error_page 497 301 =307 https://$host:3000$request_uri;

  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header REQUEST_URI $request_uri;

  location / {
    set $originaddr http://localhost:3000$request_uri;
    proxy_pass $originaddr;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . ./
RUN npm install
RUN node -v
RUN ls -ltr
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./ /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

COPY ssl/server-*pem /etc/ssl/
CMD ls

EXPOSE 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  node-app:
    build:
      context: ./my-node-app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: my-node-app
    ports:
      - "3000:443"
    volumes:
      - "./my-node-app/src:/usr/src/app/src"
```

Comment: You're only running one container and one process in that container, and it's the nginx reverse proxy (the last `FROM` block in the Dockerfile).  You need to split this into two images (with separate Dockerfiles) and two containers (in separate `docker-compose.yml` blocks).  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes what you need to put in the `proxy_pass` line for one container to call the other.

Comment: Can you change the nodejs app? If so change it to use the `https` server class in place of the `http` one, and don't bother with nginx. Easy and waaaay less complicated

Comment: Similar question cross posted here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1038763/how-to-redirect-node-js-app-to-https-using-nginx